# HeightFIeld divided into parts - PhysX

Tags: c++, nvidia, terrain, physx

I have a terrain with a specific length and width, which take the information from he file bmp. With Shade of grey i can modify my terrain. Fine, it works great. 
Here comes the problem. 
I need my terrain divided into physically smaller parts, joined together create the original terrain. 
How can i do this? I know that its possible. Any sugestions? Where, why there?

Mys file: 
HeightField.cpp

```
#include "HeightField.h"



HeightField::HeightField(Terrain terrain, PxPhysics& sdk, PxMaterial &material, int width, int height)
{
    this->nrVertices = terrain.NumVertices;
    this->terrain = terrain;
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->fillSamples();
    this->fillDesc();
    this->aHeightField = sdk.createHeightField(hfDesc);
    this->hfGeom = new PxHeightFieldGeometry(aHeightField, PxMeshGeometryFlags(), this->terrain.dy / 255.0, this->terrain.dx, this->terrain.dz);
    this->terrainPos = new PxTransform(PxVec3(-this->terrain.dx*(this->width - 1) / 2, 0.0f, this->terrain.dz*(this->height - 1) / 2), PxQuat(3.1415 / 2.0, PxVec3(0, 1, 0)));
    this->g_pxHeightField = sdk.createRigidDynamic(*this->terrainPos);
    this->g_pxHeightField->setRigidDynamicFlag(PxRigidDynamicFlag::eKINEMATIC, true);
    PxShape* aHeightFieldShape = this->g_pxHeightField->createShape(*(this->hfGeom), material);
}


HeightField::~HeightField()
{
}


void HeightField::fillSamples()
{
    this->samples = (PxHeightFieldSample*)malloc(sizeof(PxHeightFieldSample)*(this->nrVertices));

    for (int i = 0; i < this->nrVertices; i++)
    {
        samples[i].height = this->terrain.hminfo.heightMap[i].y;
        samples[i].clearTessFlag();
    }
}

void HeightField::fillDesc()
{
    this->hfDesc.format = PxHeightFieldFormat::eS16_TM;
    this->hfDesc.nbColumns = this->width;
    this->hfDesc.nbRows = this->height;
    this->hfDesc.samples.data = this->samples;
    this->hfDesc.samples.stride = sizeof(PxHeightFieldSample);
}
```

Terrain.cpp

```
#include "Terrain.h"


Terrain::Terrain(void)
{
    v = NULL;
    indices = NULL;
    dx = dz = 1000; //odleg³oœæ miêdzy punktami grid'a 
    dy = 1000; //maksymalna wysokoœæ terenu
}


Terrain::~Terrain(void)
{
    if (v != NULL) delete [] v;
    if (indices != NULL) delete indices;
    if (hminfo.heightMap != NULL) delete [] hminfo.heightMap;
}

bool Terrain::HeightMapLoad(char* filename, float sx, float sz, float maxy)
{
    FILE *filePtr;                          // Point to the current position in the file
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;      // Structure which stores information about file
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;      // Structure which stores information about image
    int imageSize, index;
    unsigned char height;

    // Open the file
    filePtr = fopen(filename,"rb");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
        return 0;

    dx = sz;
    dz = sz;
    dy = maxy;



    // Get the width and height (width and length) of the image
    hminfo.terrainWidth =  bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth;
    hminfo.terrainHeight = bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight;


    // Initialize the heightMap array (stores the vertices of our terrain)
    hminfo.heightMap = new IntV3[hminfo.terrainWidth * hminfo.terrainHeight];

    // We use a greyscale image, so all 3 rgb values are the same, but we only need one for the height
    // So we use this counter to skip the next two components in the image data (we read R, then skip BG)
    int k=0;

    // Read the image data into our heightMap array
    for(int j=0; j< hminfo.terrainHeight; j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i< hminfo.terrainWidth; i++)
        {
            height = bitmapImage[k];

            index = ( hminfo.terrainWidth * (hminfo.terrainHeight - 1 - j)) + i;

            hminfo.heightMap[index].x = i - (hminfo.terrainWidth - 1)/2;
            hminfo.heightMap[index].y = height;
            hminfo.heightMap[index].z = j - (hminfo.terrainHeight - 1)/2;

            k+=3;
        }
        k++;
    }


    int cols = hminfo.terrainWidth;
    int rows = hminfo.terrainHeight;

    //Create the grid
    NumVertices = 2 * rows * cols;
    NumFaces  = (rows-1)*(cols-1)*2;

    v = new struct HeightFieldVertex[NumVertices];

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for(DWORD j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            v[i*cols+j].pos.x = hminfo.heightMap[i*cols+j].x * dx;
            v[i*cols+j].pos.y = (float(hminfo.heightMap[i*cols+j].y)/255.0) * dy;
            v[i*cols+j].pos.z = hminfo.heightMap[i*cols+j].z * dz;
            v[i*cols+j].texCoord = D3DXVECTOR2(j, i);
        }
    }

    indices = new DWORD[NumFaces * 3];

    k = 0;
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < rows-1; i++)
    {
        for(DWORD j = 0; j < cols-1; j++)
        {
            indices[k]   = i*cols+j;        // Bottom left of quad
            indices[k+1] = i*cols+j+1;      // Bottom right of quad
            indices[k+2] = (i+1)*cols+j;    // Top left of quad
            indices[k+3] = (i+1)*cols+j;    // Top left of quad
            indices[k+4] = i*cols+j+1;      // Bottom right of quad
            indices[k+5] = (i+1)*cols+j+1;  // Top right of quad

            k += 6; // next quad
        }
    }

    //normals & tangents
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3> tempNormal;

    //normalized and unnormalized normals
    D3DXVECTOR3 unnormalized(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    //tangent stuff
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3> tempTangent;

    D3DXVECTOR3 tangent(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float tcU1, tcV1, tcU2, tcV2;

    //Used to get vectors (sides) from the position of the verts
    float vecX, vecY, vecZ;

    //Two edges of our triangle
    D3DXVECTOR3 edge1(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 edge2(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    //Compute face normals
    //And Tangents
    for(int i = 0; i < NumFaces; ++i)
    {
        //Get the vector describing one edge of our triangle (edge 0,2)
        vecX = v[indices[(i*3)+1]].pos.x - v[indices[(i*3)]].pos.x;
        vecY = v[indices[(i*3)+1]].pos.y - v[indices[(i*3)]].pos.y;
        vecZ = v[indices[(i*3)+1]].pos.z - v[indices[(i*3)]].pos.z;       
        edge1 = D3DXVECTOR3(vecX, vecY, vecZ);    //Create our first edge

        //Get the vector describing another edge of our triangle (edge 2,1)
        vecX = v[indices[(i*3)+2]].pos.x - v[indices[(i*3)]].pos.x;
        vecY = v[indices[(i*3)+2]].pos.y - v[indices[(i*3)]].pos.y;
        vecZ = v[indices[(i*3)+2]].pos.z - v[indices[(i*3)]].pos.z;     
        edge2 = D3DXVECTOR3(vecX, vecY, vecZ);    //Create our second edge

        //Cross multiply the two edge vectors to get the un-normalized face normal
        D3DXVec3Cross(&unnormalized, &edge1, &edge2);
        tempNormal.push_back(unnormalized);

        //Find first texture coordinate edge 2d vector
        tcU1 = v[indices[(i*3)+1]].texCoord.x - v[indices[(i*3)]].texCoord.x;
        tcV1 = v[indices[(i*3)+1]].texCoord.y - v[indices[(i*3)]].texCoord.y;

        //Find second texture coordinate edge 2d vector
        tcU2 = v[indices[(i*3)+2]].texCoord.x - v[indices[(i*3)]].texCoord.x;
        tcV2 = v[indices[(i*3)+2]].texCoord.y - v[indices[(i*3)]].texCoord.y;

        //Find tangent using both tex coord edges and position edges
        tangent.x = (tcV2 * edge1.x - tcV1 * edge2.x)  / (tcU1 * tcV2 - tcU2 * tcV1);
        tangent.y = (tcV2 * edge1.y - tcV1 * edge2.y)  / (tcU1 * tcV2 - tcU2 * tcV1);
        tangent.z = (tcV2 * edge1.z - tcV1 * edge2.z)  / (tcU1 * tcV2 - tcU2 * tcV1);

        tempTangent.push_back(tangent);
    }

    //Compute vertex normals (normal Averaging)
    D3DXVECTOR4 normalSum(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR4 tangentSum(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    int facesUsing = 0;
    float tX, tY, tZ;   //temp axis variables

    //Go through each vertex
    for(int i = 0; i < NumVertices; ++i)
    {
        //Check which triangles use this vertex
        for(int j = 0; j < NumFaces; ++j)
        {
            if(indices[j*3] == i ||
                indices[(j*3)+1] == i ||
                indices[(j*3)+2] == i)
            {
                tX = normalSum.x + tempNormal[j].x;
                tY = normalSum.y + tempNormal[j].y;
                tZ = normalSum.z + tempNormal[j].z;

                normalSum = D3DXVECTOR4(tX, tY, tZ, 0.0f);  //If a face is using the vertex, add the unormalized face normal to the normalSum

                facesUsing++;
            }
        }
        //Get the actual normal by dividing the normalSum by the number of faces sharing the vertex
        normalSum = normalSum / facesUsing;

        facesUsing = 0;
        //Check which triangles use this vertex
        for(int j = 0; j < NumFaces; ++j)
        {
            if(indices[j*3] == i ||
                indices[(j*3)+1] == i ||
                indices[(j*3)+2] == i)
            {

                //We can reuse tX, tY, tZ to sum up tangents
                tX = tangentSum.x + tempTangent[j].x;
                tY = tangentSum.y + tempTangent[j].y;
                tZ = tangentSum.z + tempTangent[j].z;

                tangentSum = D3DXVECTOR4(tX, tY, tZ, 0.0f); //sum up face tangents using this vertex

                facesUsing++;
            }
        }
        //Get the actual normal by dividing the normalSum by the number of faces sharing the vertex
        tangentSum = tangentSum / facesUsing;

        //Normalize the normalSum vector and tangent
        D3DXVec4Normalize(&normalSum, &normalSum);
        D3DXVec4Normalize(&tangentSum, &tangentSum);

        //Store the normal and tangent in our current vertex
        v[i].normal.x = normalSum.x;
        v[i].normal.y = normalSum.y;
        v[i].normal.z = normalSum.z;

        v[i].tangent.x = tangentSum.x;
        v[i].tangent.y = tangentSum.y;
        v[i].tangent.z = tangentSum.z;

        D3DXVECTOR3 bit;

        D3DXVec3Cross(&bit, &v[i].normal, &v[i].tangent);
        v[i].bitangent = -1.0 * bit;

        //Clear normalSum, tangentSum and facesUsing for next vertex
        normalSum = D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        tangentSum = D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        facesUsing = 0;
    }

    ////terrain AABB
    //MinX =  -1.0 * dx * (hminfo.terrainWidth - 1)/2;
    //MinY = 0.0;
    //MinZ =  -1.0 * dz * (hminfo.terrainHeight - 1)/2;
    //MaxX =  dx * (hminfo.terrainWidth - 1)/2;
    //MaxY = dy;
    //MaxZ =  dz * (hminfo.terrainHeight - 1)/2;

    return true;
}
```

Fragment of Base.cpp

```
HeightField *hf = new HeightField(g_Terrain, *g_PhysicsSDK, *material, g_Terrain.hminfo.terrainWidth, g_Terrain.hminfo.terrainHeight);
    g_PxScene->addActor(*(hf->g_pxHeightField));
```

I want to get something similar, but in order to work correctly
[PVD - simulation Terrain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXUUq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the website [rastertek](http://www.rastertek.com) for working with DirectX 10 or 11 in c++ within his updated DirectX 11 Terrain Series or version 2 a similar construct was created in tutorial 9 in which he calls Terrain Cells. The direct link to that tutorial can be found here: [DirectX 11: Terrain Series2: Tutorial 9 - Terrain Cells](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11ter09.html). This should provide an excellent reference that I think is related toward the topic at hand and your initial question.